# How to use qemu to run Buildroot Linux images?

Tags: embedded, qemu, buildroot

I have compiled an embedded Linux with Buildroot for i386. I didn't edited much, just defaults. Now I want to run it under qemu. But the only thing I see is this:
[image]

I'm running qemu with these options:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel vmlinux -hda rootfs.ext2 -m 256
```

Why this is happening? I have compiled like the example in the buildroot documentation.

Comment: Without details how/what you did or what the exact problem is we can't help you. Try to use the serial option for qemu to determine problem. You probably want to specify `-append` as an option to qemu if your kernel has no default parameters, e.g. you should at least specify the root partition.

Comment: what info I should provide so it can help you? kernel config file? uclibc config file?

Comment: Well, `rootfs.ext2` is the image from filesystem while you are passing it as a disk image. (it does not contain partition table and MBR). The correct command must be something like:
`qemu-system-i386 -kernel vmlinux file=rootfs.ext2,format=raw -m 256`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Commands that just work**

To make absolutely sure that it will work, we can make Buildroot build QEMU for us, and use the exact QEMU CLI provided by Buildroot at: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2019.05/board/qemu/x86_64/readme.txt

```
git clone https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot
cd buildroot
git checkout 2019.05
make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
printf '
BR2_CCACHE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU_LINUX_USER_MODE=n
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU_SYSTEM_MODE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_QEMU_VDE2=y
' >> .config
make olddefconfig
time make BR2_JLEVEL="$(nproc)" HOST_QEMU_OPTS='--enable-sdl --with-sdlabi=2.0'
./output/host/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -M pc \
  -kernel output/images/bzImage \
  -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw \
  -append "rootwait root=/dev/vda" \
  -net nic,model=virtio \
  -net user \
;
```

You are now left on a shell and you can login with username `root` (no password).

[image]

Note however that the default Buildroot build does not have an interesting GUI like X11 by default, as that is not the most common use case for this project. I have covered that at: [How to install X11 on my own Linux Buildroot system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70931/how-to-install-x11-on-my-own-linux-buildroot-system/306116#306116)

But because Buildroot does not focus enough on the run part to my needs (more automation, more boot types, GDB step debug), I extended it with some extra scripts on this project: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat

Other ISAs mentioned at: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#buildroot-hello-world

Buildroot 2019.08 QEMU build failed because QEMU 3.1.1 release has a broken x86_64 build... [QEMU 3.1.1 failed to build](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535047/qemu-3-1-1-failed-to-build)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: With X11, the keyboard is screwed up when I try to log in. With `-nographic` + `console=ttyAMA0`, the output hangs after `Booting from ROM..`. Any idea how to get the nographic mode working? (note I'm doing this over SSH)

Comment: @SridharSarnobat you have to enable a serial and then telnet into its port as shown at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/6936bd6ba996dee40f7cd826e5cf01ef39c2cabf#tty You need `-serial` to enable serial, modify the `inittab` to place a shell there, and then telnet into the port. The setup in that repo already does this by default, initially for docker usage: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/6936bd6ba996dee40f7cd826e5cf01ef39c2cabf#docker