# How to install X11 on my own Linux Buildroot system?

Tags: linux, x11, linux-kernel, package-management, buildroot

I have developed my own tiny linux file system using **buildroot** and **busybox**. I used linux-2.6.38.8 kernel  configured and cross-compiled for target system(X86) according to needs.Now the filesystem is built but it has only busybox shell and it doesn't support GUI.It does not have any package-manager too.Now I want to enable GUI on it. I checked **/etc** but there was not any **x11** directory or **x11.conf** file.It does not support **startx** too.

```
How can I install x11(XFree86 or Xorg) on my system Explicitly.

I also want to install a package-manager for my system.
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe, you'll have to do it from the sources.

Comment: You'll have to build X on your own.

Comment: You can suggest any links?

Comment: You'll need a lot of time on your hands for this.... http://www.x.org/wiki/

Comment: Can be very very involved but here's XF86: http://www.xfree86.org/

Comment: @Stephan not any more after an X11 package was added to Buildroot :-) http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306116/32558

Answer (score 10):

**Ubuntu 16.04 host, Buildroot 2017.02**

[image]

Current Buildroot has an X11 package which makes things "easy" for us: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/2016.05/package/x11r7

This repo builds the entire system for you in a single command: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/b134f3958884ce1fce2dd9d31d19ab0c0fbe9089#x11

Alternatively, here is a pre-parared `.config` file: https://github.com/cirosantilli/buildroot-configs/blob/44b45b5c7f68e44abcda360a2b980f8301901a9a/qemu_x86_64_x11_defconfig

This is the minimal X11 specific configurations I managed get away with is:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_TWM=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XCALC=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XCLOCK=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XEYES=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XAPP_XINIT=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_INPUT_MOUSE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_CIRRUS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBDEV=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_VESA=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XORG7=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XSERVER_XORG_SERVER=y
BR2_PACKAGE_XTERM=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_CXX=y
BR2_TOOLCHAIN_BUILDROOT_WCHAR=y
BR2_USE_WCHAR=y
```

Here is how you can add those options to your existing `.config`: [Is it possible to use config fragments with Buildroot's .config? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078245/is-it-possible-to-use-config-fragments-with-buildroots-config/44232168#44232168)

How I found the options out: `make menuconfig`, search option names with `/`, then work backwards `dependes` from `xeyes`.

Unfortunately, you still need to know what you are doing, mainly because of situations where two different packages implement an interface (e.g. X.Org Modular vs KDrive both of which implement an X11 server), and none is selected by default.

This article helped a lot: 
[Building a tiny X.Org Linux System using Buildroot | agentoss.wordpress.com](https://agentoss.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/building-a-tiny-x-org-linux-system-using-buildroot/)

Then just the usual:

```
make BR2_JLEVEL=$(nproc)
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -M pc \
    -m 512 \
    -kernel output/images/bzImage \
    -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw \
    -append root=/dev/vda \
    -net nic,model=virtio \
    -net user
```

And from inside QEMU:

```
root
startx
```

Image size: 28M.

**Outcome**

An archaic X11 system!

And it behaves just like on this video: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/5/52/TWM_without_configuration.ogv/TWM_without_configuration.ogv.480p.webm

In particular, this archaic window manager does not have an X close button on menu bars: you had to:

- click on the desktop
- select "kill" from a menu
- select the window you want to kill

`startx` then passes `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` to `xinit`, which calls it after starting up the GUI. The default `xinitrc` contains:

```
twm &
xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
```

which starts our window manager `twm` (try changing it for one of the other managers for which Buildroot has packages), and the programs we see on the screen. TODO what is that `exec xterm` part? Why the `exec`?

**x11vnc**

[image]

When you move away from the emulator to a real device, `x11vnc` dispenses you from buying a display: it opens the screen as a window in your host, and can even send mouse clicks to the device.

Enable the `x11vnc` package on Buildroot and rebuild.

To test on QEMU first, use the options (see also [How to SSH from host to guest using QEMU? | Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124681/ssh-from-host-to-guest-using-qemu)
):

```
-net nic,model=virtio \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::5901-:5900
```

then on guest `startx`, and run:

```
x11vnc
```

And back on host:

```
sudo apt-get install vinagre
vinagre localhost::5901
```

Outcome:

- on left, QEMU running X11, x11vnc and glmark2
- on right, vinagre on host, showing the exact same thing
- I can click and interact with either one, and the other updates instantly

See also: [How to set up Raspberry Pi without a monitor? | Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14611/how-to-set-up-raspberry-pi-without-a-monitor?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Display manager (failed attempt)**

[image]

If you want to forget about the terminal completely, also enable:

- Target packages

  - Graphic libraries and applications

    - `X.Org X Window System`: both click `y` and then `enter` to go in

      - `X11R7 Applications`

        - `xconsole` (run by `xdm` by default)
        - `xdm`

Now when you start QEMU, you are presented with a graphical login screen like "modern" distros:

TODO: cannot login. Username `root` / empty password was working for me on another test with ALL X11 packages installed. `xdm` puts logs under `/var/log/xdm.log`, and you can get a TTY shell to inspect it with: [How can I ctrl-alt-f# to get to a TTY in a QEMU session? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/54824/52975)

The call chain that starts the display manager is:

- `/init` (provided by BusyBox)
- `/etc/inittab` line `::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS`
- `/etc/init.d/rcS`
- `/etc/init.d/S99xdm`
- `/usr/bin/xdm`

Comment: Can't do the same in the 2022 version https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697669

Comment: @alexanderzhirov yes, I had noticed it broke on newer buildroot as well: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/x11-buildroot-mouse-not-moving It's just not used enough I guess, since most project users are embedded. I hope one day we'll have a distro builder that works well on both desktop and embedded, including cross arch. I did a bit of investigation at: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/linux-distro-choice but didn't find THE ONE yet.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to build X on your own. Begin by reading [this X.Org wiki entry](http://www.x.org/wiki/ModularDevelopersGuide).

> This guide is for developers who wish to build the X Window System from source. If your area of interest is limited to a single package, like a driver or an application, check with your O/S first for development facilities.

As for a package manager, you will need to choose one, satisfy all needed dependencies and then package stuff for it (just because you chose dpkg/rpm/whatever, does not mean that deb/RPM/... packages will magically work with your distro). Pacman, from Arch Linux, looks easy enough to build.

Comment: Maybe support has been added since: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/tree/aa6fd11feebffe16d0b0396e0e7ad421ec061272/package/x11r7 but I haven't managed to make it run yet.

Comment: OK, managed to get it working: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/306116/32558