# How to SSH from host to guest using QEMU?

Tags: networking, ssh, qemu

How do I setup ssh from the host to the guest using qemu? I am able to use port redirection when I boot the VM without any special parameters, as follows:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -hda ubuntu1204 -m 512 -redir tcp:7777::8001
```

But when I try to boot using the following:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-m 1024 \
-name vserialtest \
-hda ubuntu1204 \
-chardev socket,host=localhost,port=7777,server,nowait,id=port1-char \
-device virtio-serial \
-device virtserialport,id=port1,chardev=port1-char,name=org.fedoraproject.port.0 \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp:7777::8001
```

I get the following error and the VM does not boot:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -net user,hostfwd=tcp:7777::8001: invalid host
forwarding rule 'tcp:7777::8001'
qemu-system-x86_64: -net user,hostfwd=tcp:7777::8001: Device 'user'
could not be initialized
```

Please note that I am able to boot the VM without the `-net` parameter
without any issues, however, I want to setup ssh from the host to the
guest. ssh from guest to host works fine as expected.

#### Edit

I have tried using

```
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:8001
```

as well as

```
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::7777:8001
```

but still the error persists and the VM does not boot.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think that the error does not come from the `-net` statement, but from:

```
-chardev socket,host=localhost,port=7777,server,nowait,id=port1-char
```

The statement uses already the port `7777`. For the port forwarding, with

```
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:8001
```

It works fine when not setting up the virtio serial channel.

If I understand right, you want to set up a virtio serial channel to communicate from the host to the VM using a Unix Domain Socket?

In this case, the following could do the job:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-m 1024 \
-name vserialtest \
-hda ubuntu1204 \
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/port1,server=on,wait=off,id=port1-char \
-device virtio-serial \
-device virtserialport,id=port1,chardev=port1-char,name=org.fedoraproject.port.0 \
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:8001
```

An example of how to connect from the host using ssh to the VM:

```
-net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22
-net nic
```

This host-forwarding maps the localhost (host) port 10022 to the port 22 on the VM.
Once the VM was started like this, you can access it from the localhost as follows:

```
ssh vmuser@localhost -p10022
```

The -net nic command initializes a very basic virtual network interface card.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am trying to use virtio-serial to establish communication from host to guest. The VM has booted giving a warning at the host console: `Warning: vlan 0 with no nics` but when I do `ifconfig` on the guest I see only `lo` and I still get `ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out` when I try to ssh; the IP I used to ssh is 10.0.2.15, which according to `man qemu-system-x86_64` is the IP assigned to the first VM booted if static IP is not assigned. And now there is no internet connection on the guest.

Comment: What you might want to do is to map the port 22 used for ssh on another port and then connect to it from the host machine to access the VM. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: The edited answer works perfectly!

Comment: It can be shortened on recent qemu versions with "-nic user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22" without the second "-net nic"

Comment: You saved my life dude!

Answer (score 34):

Add this to your qemu network config:

```
,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

*e.g.*

```
qemu -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

The `tcp::2222-:22` flag maps port 2222 of the host machine to port 22 (the default SSH port) on the virtual machine.

Then, simply SSHing to port 2222 on your localhost (the host machine) will redirect any traffic into the SSH port in the virtual machine, which should allow you to ssh as you normally would any other machine:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux!  We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just say "Try this ..."; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Comment: I just feel the need to say that this answer helped me more than all the other answers above. No superfluous information and above all, it works. Perfect when landing from a google-query "how the heck do I ssh into qemu".

Comment: This answer does what 99.9% of people actually want. I.e. host machine gets ssh access to virtual machine, including the ability for the host to copy files to and from the virtual machine using scp or similar.

Comment: Brilliant! My Raspberry Pi command now looks like `qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw console=ttyAMA0,115200" -hda 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img -nographic -redir tcp:2222::22`

Comment: `man qemu-system-x86_64` 2.5.0: Note: Legacy stand-alone options -tftp, -bootp, -smb and -redir are still processed and applied to -net user.

Comment: this is deprecated, but works great still ATM

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, I guess the non-deprecated equivalent is: `qemu -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22`

Comment: `qemu-system-x86_64: -redir: invalid option`

Comment: Adding `,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22` to my network config worked for me.

Comment: Is this an argument of starting the VM, or you have a `qemu` command that does system-wide config?

Answer (score 11):

**OpenSSH configuration tested on Buildroot 2016.05, QEMU 2.5.0, Ubuntu 16.04 host**

Besides the QEMU network forwarding, you also need to setup SSH properly, which I'll cover here.

Start with `qemu_x86_64_defconfig` and enable the openssh package:

```
make qemu_x86_64_defconfig
echo 'BR2_PACKAGE_OPENSSH=y' >> .config
make BR2_JLEVEL=$(nproc)
```

Then start QEMU with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -M pc \
  -append root=/dev/vda \
  -drive file=output/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw \
  -enable-kvm \
  -kernel output/images/bzImage \
  -m 512 \
  -net nic,model=virtio \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22
```

Then on guest:

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Modify the following settings:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

And restart the server:

```
/etc/init.d/S50sshd restart
```

It is because this file exists that sshd starts by default, here is the source: https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2018.02/package/openssh/S50sshd and the key startup operations are:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
/usr/sbin/sshd
touch /var/lock/sshd
```

Then from host:

```
ssh root@localhost -p 2222
```

In case of failure, first test that the networking forwarding is working with a lower level tool than sshd: e.g. `nc -l` [as described here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/900ccd31fb7cfc71333f0935d01180633c4d818c#host-to-guest).

also check the server logs on guest:

```
less /var/log/messages
```

Then on the final system you should automate the creation of that log file with `BR2_ROOTFS_OVERLAY` or  `BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT`: [Customizing the generated target filesystem | buildroot.org](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rootfs-custom)

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106012/how-to-access-raspberry-pi-qemu-vm-via-network

Comment: This is very specific to embedded systems; but comprehensive.

Comment: What's the difference between adding `hostfwd` to `-net` vs `-redir` option [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44065257/3310334)?

Comment: @theonlygusti I think `-redir` is a deprecated flag: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124681/how-to-ssh-from-host-to-guest-using-qemu/307557?noredirect=1#comment540649_196074

Answer (score 4):

Answers here all seem somewhat out of date or overly specific to the poster's exact situation. In general you can enable ssh by adding this to your qemu command:

```
-device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22
```

Then once it's up and running (make sure you have openssh-server installed on guest), you can ssh in from the host with:

```
ssh guestUserName@localhost -p 5555
```

See [here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking) under "How to get SSH access to a guest" for more details

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to use `hostfwd=tcp::7777-:8001` or `hostfwd=tcp::7777:8001`