# Incorrect operation of Linux (built in Buildroot) after startup X11

Tags: linux, kernel, buildroot

Built a Linux image in **Buildroot 2022.02**. After loading on real hardware, there is no mouse cursor display. The mouse itself is working (lit), but no visible actions occur after clicking on it. The keyboard does not work (Logitech Keyboard K120). Everything is connected via USB 2.0. The screen is black. The last thing I see in front of the black screen is the launch of the X-server. By pressing the off button, the screen is replaced by a terminal and the computer turns off. I don't understand what I missed in the configs. I can't see the logs, because the keyboard doesn't work to switch to another session.

I attach the configs and what I managed to photograph when I turned off the PC.

[.config Buildroot](https://ftp.zhirov.website/trash/config_buildroot)

[.config Linux Kernel 4.19.209](https://ftp.zhirov.website/trash/config_linux)

[image]

**UPD:** Managed to set up SSH and connect over the network to view logs. Here is the conclusion:

```
[   134.584] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.2
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   134.584] Current Operating System: Linux buildroot 4.19.204 #1 SMP Tue Apr 5 15:54:34 MSK 2022 x86_64
[   134.584] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/bzImage root=/dev/sda1 rootwait console=tty1
[   134.584]  
[   134.584] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   134.584]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   134.584] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   134.584] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.0.log", Time: Tue Apr  5 13:11:22 2022
[   134.586] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   134.612] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   134.612] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   134.612] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   134.612] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   134.613] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   134.613] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   134.613] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   134.613] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   134.613] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   134.613] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   134.635] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11//TTF/" does not exist.
[   134.635]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   134.635] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11//OTF/" does not exist.
[   134.635]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   134.635] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11//Type1/" does not exist.
[   134.635]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   134.635] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11//100dpi/".
[   134.635]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   134.635]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11//100dpi/").
[   134.636] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11//75dpi/".
[   134.636]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   134.636]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11//75dpi/").
[   134.636] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11//misc/
[   134.636] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   134.636] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   134.636] (II) Loader magic: 0x55cffd178020
[   134.636] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   134.636]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   134.636]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[   134.636]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[   134.636]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   134.637] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   134.637] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/drm/card0
[   134.641] (--) PCI:*(0@0:1:0) 1002:9851:1565:170a rev 64, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xe0000000/8388608, 0xfea00000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000f000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   134.641] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   134.641] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[   134.641] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[   134.641] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[   134.641] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[   134.641] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   134.641] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   134.644] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[   134.644] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[   134.644] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   134.644] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   134.662] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   134.662]    compiled for 1.21.1.2, module version = 1.21.1
[   134.662]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   134.662]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   134.662] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   134.662] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   134.668] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so: (null)
[   134.668] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (loader failed, 0)
[   134.668] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   134.668] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   134.675] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so: (null)
[   134.675] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (loader failed, 0)
[   134.675] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   134.675] (++) using VT number 1

[   134.675] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[   134.676] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[   134.676] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   134.676] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   134.676] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[   134.676] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   134.676] (II) modeset(0): No glamor support in the X Server
.............
```

**UPD:** Video drivers are included in the build. The config files are attached just above.

```
#
# xf86-video-amdgpu needs egl/opengl support from mesa3d
#
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_ARK is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_AST is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_ATI=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_CIRRUS is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_DUMMY is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBDEV=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBTURBO is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_GLINT is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_I128 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_INTEL is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_MACH64 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_MGA is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_NEOMAGIC is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_NOUVEAU is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_NV is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_OPENCHROME is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_QXL is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_R128 is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_SAVAGE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_SILICONMOTION is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_SIS is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_TDFX is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_TGA is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_TRIDENT is not set
BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_VESA=y
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_VMWARE is not set
# BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_VOODOO is not set
```

Comment: I would add X11 on title BTW.

Comment: This smells like you didn't include the graphics driver in your buildroot image. How about `BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_FBDEV=y` and `BR2_PACKAGE_XDRIVER_XF86_VIDEO_VESA=y`?

Comment: Video drivers are included in the build. The config files are attached just above. @Philippos