# QEMU 3.1.1 failed to build

Tags: linux-mint, virtual-machine, qemu

[OS=Linux Mint 19.2]

I'm trying to build this version of QEMU so I can experiment with 3D acceleration. But every time I try the build, it always fails. Here are my configuration parameters:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/qemu3 \
        --target-list=x86_64-softmmu \
        --audio-drv-list=pa,alsa,oss \
        --enable-gtk \
        --disable-vte \
        --enable-opengl \
        --enable-sdl \
        --with-sdlabi=2.0 \
        --enable-virglrenderer
```

This works. Now, when I run `make`, it fails on the rdma build:

```
  CC      x86_64-softmmu/hw/rdma/rdma_utils.o
  CC      x86_64-softmmu/hw/rdma/rdma_backend.o
  CC      x86_64-softmmu/hw/rdma/rdma_rm.o
  CC      x86_64-softmmu/hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_dev_ring.o
  CC      x86_64-softmmu/hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.o
/home/me/Development/source/qemu-3.1.1/hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.c: In function ‘create_qp’:
/home/me/Development/source/qemu-3.1.1/hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.c:517:16: error: ‘rc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         return rc;
                ^~
/home/me/Development/source/qemu-3.1.1/hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.c:517:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/me/Development/source/qemu-3.1.1/rules.mak:69: recipe for target 'hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.o' failed
make[1]: *** [hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:483: recipe for target 'subdir-x86_64-softmmu' failed
make: *** [subdir-x86_64-softmmu] Error 2
```

I have the `librdmacm-dev` library installed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re not doing anything wrong, the code is buggy.

You should replace

```
return rc;
```

on [line 517 of `hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.c`](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=hw/rdma/vmw/pvrdma_cmd.c;h=bb9a9f1cd17d7cc1dc38c35a5fb2e3708a424dfb;hb=71049d2a745803d400e21ef93b113a70390853a8#l517) with

```
goto out;
```

Comment: Is there a bug report / patch upstream?

Comment: @Ciro yes, see [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2019-08/msg01911.html).

Comment: Awesome, thanks, Stephen!